# Jquery alert the value of a custom attribute

Tags: jquery

can somebody please help me in displaying the value of "code" from the dropdown element's attribute.  Sorry I am very new to Jquery.  Example I want to alert the alue of Afghanistan which whould be 93.

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="requiredInput" tabindex="5">
<option class="no-op" value="">-- Please select --</option>
<option value="977270" code="93">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="977271" code="355">Albania</option>
<option value="977272" code="213">Algeria</option>
<option value="977273" code="1684">American Samoa</option>
<option value="977274" code="376">Andorra</option>
<option value="977275" code="AO">Angola</option>
<option value="977276" code="AI">Anguilla</option>
<option value="977277" code="AQ">Antarctica</option>
<option value="977278" code="AG">Antigua</option></select>
```

Comment: when do you want to display it? where do you want to display it

Comment: `$('#country option:selected').attr('code')`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jmdr4/1/

Comment: I would suggest you to use `data-` prefix attribute

Comment: unfortunately I can not use data- prefix since the page is dynamically created from another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    alert($("option:selected", this).attr('code'));
});
```

@Satpal suggested a better & faster way, using `.find()`:

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr('code'));
});
```

hope that helps.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zmv7/)

However, I would suggest you to use `data-` prefix attribute. like

```
<option value="977270" data-code="93">Afghanistan</option>
```

Then you can use

```
alert($(this).find("option:selected").data('code'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use `data-*` instead, for example:

```
<option value="977270" data-code="93">Afghanistan</option>
```

then you can do something like this:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
    var code = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-code');
    alert(code);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KeG3V/)**

Comment: If you're using `data-*` you can also find `attr` value by `$(this).find('option:selected').data('code')`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the Jquery event as::

```
$("#country").change(function(){
    alert($("#country :selected").attr('data-code'));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/6vWWN/

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected option's code by:

```
var code = $('#country').find(':selected').attr('code');
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use custom `data-*` attribute:

```
data-code="93"// <----if you can change it like this
```

then you can get it like this:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
   var codeVal = $(this).find('option:selected').data('code');
   alert(codeVal);  //----use data here----------^^^^
});
```

#### [Demo with data-*](http://jsfiddle.net/TVT5H/)

or with your current markup:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
   var codeVal = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('code');
   alert(codeVal);  //----use attr here----------^^^^
});
```

#### [Demo with attr](http://jsfiddle.net/TVT5H/1/)

Comment: thank you very, unfortunately I can not use custom data-* attribute but your third suggestion works.  thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Glad we suggested you some solutions which worked for you.